# macOS Catalina Preview.app cannot create signature with built-in camera

Tags: catalina, preview, bug, signature

I'm on macOS Catalina 10.15.6 19G2021 x86_64.

I was trying to create a signature with Preview.app and the MacBook's built-in camera, when I clicked on `Done` button, the captured signature wasn't saved.

I tried to restart Preview.app, reopen the document and open another document and it still didn't work.

Is it a bug? What should I do? Thanks!

[image]

Preview.app version from "About Preview":
[image: Preview.app version from "About Preview"]

Comment: Did it show in the capture window before you clicked Done?

Comment: Have you tried restarting preview? Have you restarted your computer? Did you actually see a signature preview before you clicked done?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes. The captured signature was shown in that window.

Comment: @virus.cmd I tried to restart Preview.app, reopen the document and open another document and it still didn't work. I won't be restarting the computer now. And yes, I've seen the signature before clicking 'Done'. :)

Comment: I guess I'll wait until the next time I restart my mac and try it again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hold your signature ON the blue line, like that was a line on a page where you are signing.

The camera's view of your paper is mirror image. However, once Preview detects your signature, it will digitise it and display it correctly (non-mirror), and in a way that looks like you'd actually signed the screen (i.e. it's not just a picture of your paper).

In the image below you can see the digitised image in black, with my paper, with blue ink, somewhat obscured in the background:
[image: Signature detected]